# How to make sensor input look like high impedance on loss of 5V power?

Tags: circuit-protection, instrumentation-amplifier, strain-gage

I have a strain gauge sensor with a full-scale output of about 8mV and an output impedance of 5K ohms.  We will be measuring its value with a max sample rate of 500Hz, and 10 bits of resolution.  It will connect to my circuit card via a wiring harness.  On the circuit card the signal goes to an instrumentation amplifier (INA818).

In order to improve reliability in case of a fault on the card, we are planning to have two identical circuit cards redundantly sense and process the strain gauge signal.  Each card then independently reports the results out over a network.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fv7zJQ.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

There is one fault scenario where this dual connection doesn't improve reliability.  If any of the many components connected to the 5V power supply of either CCA were to become shorted, then the instrumentation amplifier on that CCA would no longer look like high impedance and would short out the sensor through the ESD diodes on the INA818.

**I am interested in finding good ways to ensure that the connection to the sensor looks like high impedance (less than 1nA of leakage) if the power supply drops below 4.5V.**  Note that this question is not concerned with the possibility of the 5V supplies going above 5V, only the case of a short on the supply.

Comment: The most unreliable component will likely be the sensors themselves so, maybe you might have taken your eye off the ball here?

Comment: I'm with Andy. maybe have another redundant set of gauges/amp or an alternate means of verifying the load cell operation. If a gauge delaminates, then it is electrically difficult to tell apart from the massive drift in the readout. The effects of delamination usually happen slowly, so the load cell is slowly dying but unless there is another means of verifying the value, your system is 'best effort' at best.

Answer (score 2):

If there are no power consumption limitations, have a DPST relay with the 5 V activating the coil. Signals would be cut when 5 V is lost.

Comment: another option is to use optical MOSFET relays "aqy212s", which can be used to pass small analog signals (only 1uA leakage at 60V, so it will be much lower at your 4V). Its used in this oscilloscope: https://github.com/drandyhaas/Haasoscope/blob/master/eagle/max10adc_v9.0_schematic.pdf

Comment: @Miron I did go with an SSR since there are vibration and lifetime issues with using a mechanical relay.  I didn't pick the AQY212S because the 1uA leakage is at 25C ambient.  As temperature increases that will go up exponentially to the point where it would be too high even at lower input voltage.  I picked the TLP3317 due to its exceptionally low 20pA leakage.  The G3VM-81PR, TLP3320, G3VM-101PR, and G3VM-41PR6 would have also been possible good choices.

Answer (score 1):

After a bit of searching I found the [TLP3317](https://toshiba.semicon-storage.com/us/semiconductor/product/isolators-solid-state-relays/photorelay-mosfet-output/detail.TLP3317.html) solid state relay, which has an amazingly low 20pA max leakage current at 80V and 25C.

My use case involves operating the part with only 2.5V across the terminals instead of 80V, but possibly elevated temperatures.  I still calculate that leakage probably isn't much worse than about 30pA in those conditions.

Combining the TLP3317 with a TLV431 gives the desired behavior.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fEF8rG.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

When the +5V supply voltage is less than 1.25V * (1+R5/R4) = 4.5125V the TLV431 is high impedance, and the solid-state relays turn off, isolating the strain gauge from amplifier with less than 30pA of leakage.

When the +5V supply voltage is more than 4.5125V then the TLV431 conducts, and the solid-state relays turn on, connecting the strain gauge to the amplifier.

R3 makes sure that any off-state leakage through the TLV431 doesn't go through the TLP3317 LEDs, possibly increasing the off-state leakage.

Comment: At 10 bits, 8.096mV FS, you have 8uV LSB. Across 175Ohm, that’s 45nA. You don’t need leakage 1000x smaller than that. You only need 45nA worst case if you need no error at all. But in a single-failure scenario, a static error may be allowed. Make sure you know from FMEA what’s actually needed as far as failure resistance. It seems like you want to overdesign this. If the card fails off (no power), there’s no error at all. Leakage currents will be identical on both inputs unless the in-amp is damaged. And then the supply voltage may still be present. Not all in-amp failures short supply!

Comment: In short, isolating inputs when supply to an amplifier card is lost may be counterproductive, or at the very least insufficient to protect against common failures, such as ESD input protection that failed shorted. INA818 is a nice amplifier, but is an overkill in terms of precision for this application, as I’m pretty sure you’re calibrating the system and static offset errors are immaterial. The in-amp could have 5mV offset and nobody would care much. At 500Hz bandwidth, you could also deal with higher noise. INA818 input protection won’t help with ESD in industrial and aerospace apps.

Comment: @Kubahasn'tforgottenMonica The INA818 has an allowed common mode range on the input of VDD+2V to VCC-2V.  For a 5V supply the input signals must be between 2V and 3V for the design to work.  In the case of no power, both inputs of the INA818 will be grounded through the ESD diodes and sit at about 0.7V.  In that case the second card can't read the inputs because they are outside the allowed common mode input range.  Even if 0.7V were in range, it wouldn't accurately reflect the sensor output.  I didn't specifically try and find an SSR with 50X leakage than the requirement, I just got lucky.

Comment: The particular strain gauge I am using has a 5K ohm output impedance and 8.192mV full scale range.  My goal was that the outputs should be disturbed very little by a failed power supply.  I chose 8.192V/1024 = 8uV.  32uV / 5K ohms = 1.6nA max leakage.  Using the TLP3317 + TLV431 is cheap, small, simple, and surpasses the requirements.

Comment: @Kubahasn'tforgottenMonica There are additional protection components not shown in the design posted here.  Much more than ESD, my particular operating environment can experience voltage surges and spikes on the main 24V power bus.  Because this design needs to be failsafe, it would be a problem if a wire in the sensor made contact with 24V and then took out the whole card including all the other sensors and processing its doing.  The protection that the INA818 offers is useful for that.

Answer (score 0):

You could use isolation resistors. A 1MOhm resistor connected to a 2.048V 175Ohm Thevenin equivalent source will flow about 2uA. That current across 175Ohm is a 0.35mV change, so ~5% FS if one wire fails shorted to VEXC or GND. If both wires fail shorted, one to VEXC, another to GND, that’s ~9% FS error. 10 bits at 8mV FS isn’t crazy resolution, so likely even higher isolation impedances could be used. Obviously, the first stage of amplification will need to be powered such that it can’t fail to below GND or above VEXC. A decent modern JFET in-amp will likely work from 4V, I’d hope, and it won’t consume all that much power.

If the application is in fail-safe HMI, then even a 10% static deflection error may be acceptable - your FMEA will determine that, I’d hope.

[image: Schematic of a fail-safe isolated strain gage bridge.]

Comment: I actually started out thinking I could just try a large isolation resistor.  It's not a bad idea at all.  But for my particular sensor it doesn't work out.  The problem was that with an 8.192mV full scale, 5K output impedance, and 2.048V offset, the required resistor was going to be like 100MEG or 1G ohms depending on how much error I could tolerate.  In that case the required input offset current of the amplifiers would need to be below 1pA.  At 25C that might be possible, but I also need to operate at elevated temperature, which drastically reduces the list of acceptable choices.